# SBT task to extract the jar created by package-src somewhere

Tags: scala, sbt

I would like to create a task that depends on another task with a jar file as output (e.g. package-src), which then extracts the resulting jar somewhere?

Note: I'm not interested in the library/method used to perform the extraction, only how I would define a task that invokes such a library or method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The relevant documentation pages are [Tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks.html) and [TaskInputs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/TaskInputs.html). For unzipping, you can use `sbt.IO.unzip(...)`.*

First, we need to define the task's key (in a `.scala` build definition). The task is going to return the set of unzipped files.

```
val unzipPackage = TaskKey[Set[File]]("unzip-package", "unzips the JAR generated by package-src")
```

Then, we add a setting like this one:

```
unzipPackage <<= (packageSrc, target in unzipPackage, streams) map { (zipFile, dir, out) =>
  IO createDirectory dir  
  val unzippedFiles = IO unzip (zipFile, dir, AllPassFilter)
  out.log.info("Unzipped %d files of %s to %s" format (unzippedFiles size, zipFile, dir))
  unzippedFiles
}
```

This let's us define the output directory as a setting, too:

```
target in unzipPackage <<= target / "unzippedPackage"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out when I get home. Just a quick question though, what is the streams key in the tuple for?  Also, if I really only need packageSrc as a dependency is it possible to call the map function on the packageSrc TaskKey directly?

Comment: nm the second question, I just looked at the manual and see that I can :)

Comment: The `streams` key is just for logging; it's called `out` inside the function block and is only used for `out.log.info`, i.e. logging on INFO level. It's not reeeeally relevant to the original question. I just thought I'd include it to show how to connect to other commonly used things. :)